# List all ip addresses for the same service within docker swarm

Tags: docker, erlang, docker-swarm, docker-cloud

I am using docker cloud and I want a service where all of the containers can locate all the other containers in the same service. The end goal is to create an erlang cluster.

I have been reading through this part of the getting started guide
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#accessing-your-cluster

As I understand it I should be able to use an ingress network and have every container be exposing the same port,

My stackfile looks like the following

```
www:
  autoredeploy: true
  deployment_strategy: high_availability
  image: 'crowdhailer/www:0.1.0'
  ports:
    - '8080'
  target_num_containers: 5
```

If I curl `www:8080` I get the response I want but I cant find a way to translate the hostname `www:8080` to a list of ips